# HTML Email to .MSG

Tags: email, html-email, msg

We've got a corporate client that insists that for internal emails they need them in .msg format in order for images to come across properly.

I'm not really familiar with the .msg format, but it sounds like it's a way to embed more than just text in the email message:

> Mail message (Microsoft) MSG is a file extension for a mail message
>   file format used by Microsoft Outlook and Exchange. An MSG file can
>   contain plain ASCII text for the headers and the main message body as
>   well as hyperlinks and attachments.

From [http://whatis.techtarget.com](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/MSG-Mail-message-Microsoft)

I'm not seeing though anything about how to set up or convert something to the format.

Do I just code the markup as a normal HTML email, send it to a mail client with Outlook (or something else that saves .msg files) and then provide that .msg file?

Is there a better way? Is there some sort of tool I should utilize for the conversion?

Comment: loading it into Outlook and saving is easiest and best way. I do not know of any other way to convert to this other than maybe through Word.  Word HTML files are what Outlook uses (Outlook 2007 +) so it will retain all formatting and images, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My successful solution was to build/code the HTML as usual and then utilize Outlook on Windows and save the file out as an Outlook file, which has the extension of .msg.

We're predominantly a Mac shop and found that Outlook 2011 on OS X does not have a way to export to .msg file format. We had to use a PC (or a VM) with Outlook install to be able to export properly.

Comment: Just wondering, does the HTML elements hold up decently in MSG? From my experience, there are some tweaking needed to get the elements right. Also, when sending out via MSG, the mobile responsiveness and background images are also sacrificed.

Comment: HTML holds up relatively well, but definitely can't use responsiveness, nor background images.

Comment: How did you do that? Would you know how to do it with PowerShell?

Comment: @SimonFerndriger Sorry. I posted this Q&A 7 years ago, and it's not something I've done at all in at least 5 years.

Comment: @Keefer Thanks, no worries, already got it solved in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630718/how-to-convert-html-email-to-msg-file-with-powershell

Comment: @SimonFerndriger So glad! Glad you were able to solve it.