# How to convert HTML email to MSG file with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, msg

I have emails as a ZIP file which contains the HTML version of it (1 html file and optional attachments). How can I convert these html emails to a .msg file using PowerShell?

It seems to be possible to at least work with Outlook:

`$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application`

And unzipping looks like an easy task according to [How to unzip a file in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768303/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-powershell)

On [HTML Email to .MSG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335954/html-email-to-msg) there is a similar question, but not really a practical answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a practical (and very simple) answer using powershell to create a .msg with a HTML body.

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$mailItem= $outlook.CreateItem([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType]::olMailItem)
$mailItem.Subject = "My Subject"
$mailItem.HTMLBody = "<h1>My Title</h1><p>Hello World</p>"
$mailItem.SaveAs("C:\temp\test.msg",[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType]::olMSG)
```

Please note:

1. you have a lot of properties in the `$mailItem` object to customize the object message (have a look at the variable)
2. you need Outlook client installed on the machine